# Approve a pull request

Tags: tfs

I need to programmatically approve a pull request, but I keep getting exceptions.

If I do this, then I catch - "System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Method Not Allowed)'
Inner Exception: VssServiceResponseException: Method Not Allowed".
"System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Method Not Allowed)'
Inner Exception: VssServiceResponseException: Method Not Allowed"

```
var pr = new GitPullRequest
        {
            MergeStatus = PullRequestAsyncStatus.Succeeded,
            Title = $"PR AUTO from {SrcBranch} into {TrgtBranch}",
            Description = $"PR AUTO from {SrcBranch} into {TrgtBranch}",
            SourceRefName = SrcBranch.Name,
            TargetRefName = TrgtBranch.Name,
            Repository = rep,
            AutoCompleteSetBy = new IdentityRef(),
            Reviewers = new IdentityRefWithVote[]
                {
                    new IdentityRefWithVote
                    {
                        DisplayName = nameReviewer,
                        Id = idReviewer,
                        ImageUrl = imageUrl,
                        ReviewerUrl = reviewerUrl,
                        UniqueName = uniqueName,
                        Url = url
                    }
                };


            var createPr = gitClient.CreatePullRequestAsync(pr, Project, RepositoryId).Result;

            var getPr = gitClient.GetPullRequestByIdAsync(createPr.PullRequestId).Result;

            var reviewer = new IdentityRefWithVote
            {
                Vote = 10
            };
                        
            var updateReviewer = gitClient.UpdatePullRequestReviewerAsync(reviewer, repository.Id, pullRequestId, reviewerId);
```

Comment: If no one is going to actually review a PR, why are you even bothering to use them? Just merge the code.

Comment: @DanielMann Can you explain why Microsoft decided to implement the API then?